# How to programmatically create UIView so that it does not overlap the status bar

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am using the following code in my app delegate to programmatically create the application's window and root controller:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.rootViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    self.window.rootViewController.view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    self.window.rootViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    return TRUE;
}
```

The code works fine, however the view associated to the root view controller overlaps the status bar, which I would like to avoid (see picture below).

[image]

How should I proceed? In particular I want to have a lightgray background for the status bar (similar to the apps created with a storyboard) and also handle orientation change correctly.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can do something as following:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.rootViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    self.window.rootViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    UIView *redView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,
                                                               [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height,
                                                               [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width,
                                                               [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)];
    redView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:redView];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return TRUE;
}
```

should look like this:

[image]